# How to grant a kerberos ticket after successful imap authentication from dovecot

Tags: debian, nfs, kerberos, pam, dovecot

An interesting question, I hope.

I am running a set of virtual machines under debian 6, to build a mail/collaboration server. I am mainly using dovecot, postfix, openldap and heimdal. Mails are stored using maildir, on a NFSv4 share.

My users are system users, but using LDAP and libpam-ldap and libnss-ldap for caching credentials information.

Everything is working as expected, well, *almost*.

Since NFS is using kerberos, by defaults, my users are not able to access their mail storage if they have not received their kerberos ticket.

For instance, if I do nothing, this is the errors I have from dovecot when trying to logon using any imap client:

> Mar 31 09:33:07 titan dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
>   Mar 31 09:33:07 titan dovecot: dovecot: Fatal: chdir(/home/emails/team/arodier/) failed: Permission denied (euid=1003(arodier) egid=1001(red2team) missing +x perm: /home/emails)
>   Mar 31 09:33:07 titan dovecot: dovecot: child 5089 (imap) returned error 89 (Fatal failure)

However, if I just login on a console for the user "*arodier*", I see that I have received a ticket, and I can see it with klist:

> Credentials cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1001_ywvktf
>           Principal: arodier@RED2.SRV
>
> Issued           Expires          Principal
>   Mar 31 09:25:55  Mar 31 19:25:53  krbtgt/RED2.SRV@RED2.SRV
>   Mar 31 09:25:57  Mar 31 19:25:53  nfs/ananke.red2.srv@RED2.SRV

Once I have simply logged myself on a console, I can access my emails using any IMAP client.

The question is:
How should I configure libpam (or dovecot ?) to initialise/receive a kerberos ticket after successful authentication ?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using password authentication, you should be able to use [pam-krb5](http://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/software/pam-krb5/) (packaged as `libpam-krb5` in Debian) to get a Kerberos TGT on behalf of your users. You will need to configure pam so that the service dovecot uses (probably `/etc/pam.d/dovecot`) or the `/etc/pam.d/common-*` files (see `/usr/share/doc/libpam-krb5/README.Debian` for details.

However, since you mention that if you log into the server from the console you already have your TGT set up for you, it may be that  you already have `libpam-krb5` installed and in use. If that's the case, it may just be a question of checking Dovecot's configuration to make sure it's using PAM correctly (in particular the session configuration, which I believe will be the part responsible for setting up the TGT). The commented dovecot.conf file I'm looking at says:

```
# session=yes makes Dovecot open and immediately close PAM session. Some
# PAM plugins need this to work, such as pam_mkhomedir.
```

so it looks like that may not be enabled by default.